# Enabling a custom module generates errors for undefined regions when blocks are enabled.

Tags: blocks, theming

A custom module defines some blocks, with this sample definition:

```
  return array(
    'info'        => 'Site Header',
    'cache'       => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, // @TODO change it later
    'status'      => TRUE,
    'region'      => 'header',
    'visibility'  => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,
  //  'page'        => '<front>',
  );
```

When enabling the module, I get the following error:

```
The block Site Header was assigned to the invalid region header and has been disabled.
```

The same happens for all blocks defined in this module. The regions exist in both admin and site theme, as I inserted a var_dump in block.admin.inc.

```
array(13) {
  ["content"]=>
  string(7) "Content"
  ["bigBox"]=>
  string(7) "Big Box"
  ["headline"]=>
  string(18) "Headline caroussel"
  ["leftCol"]=>
  string(17) "Colonne de gauche"
  ["rightCol"]=>
  string(17) "Colonne de droite"
  ["navigation"]=>
  string(14) "Navigation bar"
  ["header"]=>
  string(6) "Header"
  ["footer"]=>
  string(6) "Footer"
  ["page_top"]=>
  string(8) "Page top"
  ["page_bottom"]=>
   string(11) "Page bottom"
  ["dashboard_main"]=>
  string(16) "Dashboard (main)"
  ["dashboard_sidebar"]=>
  string(19) "Dashboard (sidebar)"
  ["dashboard_inactive"]=>
  string(20) "Dashboard (inactive)"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you running? Please see https://drupal.org/node/1172560

Comment: @pamatt - D7 is used. I saw this post before posting here, it deals with a bug in boost. At first I thought I only had to redeclare regions in subtheme but this did not work.

Comment: It's not only boost-related. It seems to be a problem with Drupal's core, which has been dealt with with Drupal 8 and probably backported to 7... have you updated Drupal to 7.23?

Comment: Please see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/128202/15055